# HERE location services API freemium plan question

Tags: maps, location-services, here-maps-rest

I am looking at HERE location services API as an alternative to Google Maps JavaScript API to use with an autosuggest input.

They state that they include 250,000 free transactions per month on the free plan. They also state 'Assets: per month 250'. What are these assets they are referring to? I can't find anything in their docs. Is an asset a single 'place details' object returned or something else?

Hopefully someone here has experience with their freemium plan and knows. Because if it's one 'place details' object that is counted as one asset, it makes this freemium plan option insufficient for my needs. I am hoping that any new character input is counted as 1/250,000 requests and subsequent 'place details' request also considered as a single request, not an asset request.

Answer (score 0):

From the FAQs:

4. What is an Asset?

An Asset is a person (including an end user), animal, device, cargo, means of transportation, vehicle or any other object which is located, tracked or displayed on a map, or provided route calculations or orders of destinations and/or routes, or has analytics derived by using the HERE Materials in a customer application or service for business purposes.

For example, HERE services are often used to help logistics providers manage vehicles in a fleet or a field workforce. If you manage 250 or fewer Assets, the Freemium and Pro plans will support your app. Contact us to license applications that manage more than 250 Assets.

Source: [HERE FAQs](https://developer.here.com/faqs)